# Replicate/duplicate first value (column A) over all columns in entire row

Tags: python, dataframe, duplicates, replicate

Does anyone know, how to get from this:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rate | RS | 1.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 |

to this:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rate | RS | RS | RS | RS | RS | RS | RS |

Comment: do you mind using a loop?

Comment: no, as long as it does the job :)

Comment: then just loop through all the columns you want to update, and assign them the first column data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using slice assignment:

```
df[:] = df.iloc[0, 0]
```

Or if you want to specify the `Rate` index:

```
>>> df[:] = df.loc['Rate'].iloc[0]
>>> df
       A   B   C   D   E   F   G
Rate  RS  RS  RS  RS  RS  RS  RS
>>>
```